# i cannot find my hiddenfield2 in the back end code

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

i cannot find my hiddenfield2 in the back end code . So how can i get the value of this hiddenfiled using asp.net(vb)

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <div class="list_election">
          <form>
       <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddlElectionCategorie" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>

          </form>
      </div>
     <div class="row">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rpVoteList" runat="server" >

        <ItemTemplate>

            <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <div class="voter">
                    <h4><%# Eval("List_Nom")%></h4>

                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfListId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id")%>' />
                    <form>
'this is a nested radiobutton list in a repeater
                         <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id")%>' />
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RbCandidat" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>

                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>


        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
     </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

C#:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpVoteList.Items)
{
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType ==  ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var hf= (HiddenField)item.FindControl("HiddenField2")
    }
}
```

Or

```
protected void rpVoteList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var value = (HiddenField) e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField2")).Value;
}
```

Comment: i need the solution in asp.net(vb)

Comment: this is not what i need. I need to get the value of the hidden field to display it in a msgbox.

Comment: or to get the value of the selected radiobutton